# Error when attempting to pass hook protocol to SetWindowsHookEx()

Tags: c++, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I've been working on a little side project as of late and I've run into an odd problem. Essentially, it's a keylogger that uses a low-level keyboard hook to record keystrokes*. This is the class I came up with.

```
class CLogger {
public:
    static CLogger *Logger();
    bool OpenLogFile(const char*, const char*);
    void WriteToLogFile(UINT, FILE*, char&);
    void __cdecl Hook();
    void __cdecl Unhook();
    LRESULT __stdcall KbdHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
private:
    CLogger() {};
    CLogger(CLogger const&) {};
    CLogger& operator = (CLogger const&) {};
    static CLogger *pLogger;
    /* ... */
    FILE *fLog = NULL;
    HHOOK _hHook;
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdstruct;
    char buffer;
};
```

The problem arises when I try to implement the `Hook()` function

```
void __cdecl CLogger::Hook() {
    if (!(_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KbdHookProc, NULL, 0))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "SetWindowsHookEx() Failed", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

Specifically, I get an error `error C3867: 'CLogger::KbdHookProc': function call missing argument list; use '&CLogger::KbdHookProc' to create a pointer to member`

I've also tried `this->KbdHookProc`, with and without parentheses and no go.

I'm fairly inexperienced so if this is an obvious fix, please forgive me. Also, to clarify this code does and has worked when I declare the hook procedure globally, but it's when it's contained in a class that it doesn't.

*All for learning purposes, of course.

Comment: Did you try following the suggestion, present in the error message?

Comment: Only static member functions can be used as the `C` callback does not know what a member function is or how to call one.

Comment: Have your tried `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &Clogger::KbdHookProc, NULL, 0)` like the error report suggests?

Comment: @Clearer Oh that's right, I tried that as well, but I got `error C2664: 'HHOOK SetWindowsHookExA(int,HOOKPROC,HINSTANCE,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'LRESULT (__stdcall CLogger::* )(int,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'HOOKPROC'`

Comment: It is a C api, it doesn't know beans about C++ member functions.  Your callback must be static and use the stdcall calling convention to conform to HOOKPROC.